# How to add the data of two columns from two tables having the same structure?

Tags: sql, oracle

Eg: I have two tables EPL1 and EPL2 which contains data of footballers who have scored, assisted, played matches etc. The structure of both the tables are exactly the same.

First Table contains stats of Ronaldo, Messi with 2 goals each.
Second Table contains stats of Ronaldo, Messi with 3 goals each.

Now I want to combine both these tables and want an output which has Ronaldo, Messi with 5 goals each.

**Most Important** thing to notice is that both the tables have the exact same structure and column names, I just want to combine(add) the values of all the columns in both tables.

So what kind of join should I use for this in Oracle?

Comment: Why do you have two tables with exactly the same structure?  This sounds like bad database design.  Usually, you would put all the rows in one table.

Comment: Why are you storing exactly the same type of information in two tables?

Comment: I am making two tables with two different leagues. And in both the leagues, the structure will be the same for eg: FA Cup and EPL will be having the same players of the same country but I would want to combine the total goals scored by each player in those two competitions. Likewise.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is with a UNION ALL statement.

```
select player, sum(goals) as goals
from 
     ( select *
       from table1
       union all
       select *
       from table2 )
group by player
```

This works well when the two tables have a identical structure (or you're just selecting a projection) and you want to select all rows from all tables.  This approach is easy to extend to three or more tables.

Note that you need to use `UNION ALL`.  The plain `UNION` operator would produce the wrong result is say you had ('XAVI', 2) in table1 and ('XAVI', 2) in table2: it applies a distinct filter, and so you would get a final result of ('XAVI', 2) instead of ('XAVI', 4).

Answer (score 0):

insert into NewTable 
select sum(goals),player (select * From EPL1 Union all select * from EPL2) group by player

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the table structure, it's a bit difficult to know the answer, but you probably need something like this

```
select epl1.name, sum(epl1.goals + epl2.goals)
from epl1
left join epl2
where epl1.name = epl2.name
group by epl1.name
```

Comment: For some reason connected to my antivirus program, I can't even edit my own answer. A better answer would be 'select epl1.name, sum (epl1.goals + epl2.goals) from epl1 left join epl2 where epl1.name = epl2.name group by epl1.name'

Answer (score 0):

Also, having two tables with the same structure is not a correct design, you can get the desired output using the following:

```
SELECT * FROM epl1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM epl2;
```